# Runtime Error 800a01c2

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I get the following error:

> Line 24 error message Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01c2'  Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.

Line 24 is:

```
set strPassword = objDB("medacist_password")
```

Full code:

```
<%
DIM strEmail
strEmail = Request.Form("email")

IF strEmail <> "" THEN
%>
<%
DIM objDB, rs, rssql
Set objDB = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objDB.Open "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Password=langas;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=mmsg;Data Source=mmsg_web"
rssql = "SELECT email_addr, medacist_password FROM medacist_user WHERE email_addr = '" & strEmail & "'"
Set rs = objDB.Execute(rssql) 
IF rs.EOF THEN
    Response.Write "That email address was not found in our database. Please click Back on your browser and enter the email address you registered with."
ELSE
    DIM strPassword
    set strPassword = objDB("medacist_password")
    DIM mail, objMail
    Set objMail = Server.CreateObject("CDOSYS.NewMail") 
    objMail.From = "clu@medacist.com"
    objMail.Subject = "Password"
    objMail.To = strEmail
    objMail.Body = "Here is your login password: " & strEmail 
    objMail.Send

    'Set objMail to nothing to destory the mail object'
    Set objMail = nothing

    Response.Write "Your password has been sent to your email address."
END IF

ELSE
    Response.Write "Please click Back on your browser and enter the email address you registered with."
END IF
%>
```

Comment: What are you trying do do on that line?  objDB("some string here") makes no sense.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `rs("medacist_password")`? You want to read from the resultset and not from the connection.

Comment: `Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")` if you're using CDOSYS

Comment: Yes, I figure out my problems were. I change CDOSYS to CDO.Message and change objDB("medacist_password") to rs("medacist_password"). Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Set" keyword in VBScript is used only to assign *objects* into variables. However, the value in the recordset isn't an object, just a plain string.

Change the code to this and it would work:

```
strPassword = rs("medacist_password")
```